# why does this program crash when input is greater than 9?

Tags: c

I dont know why this crashes on my machine but it does

You are given a positive integer, N ,:

If 1 <= N <= 9, then print the English representation of it. That is "one" for 1, "two" for 2, and so on.
Otherwise print "Greater than 9" (without quotes).
Input Format:

Input will contain only one integer, N .

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* itos2(int);

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
   int a;
   scanf("%i", &a );
   printf("%s",((a >= 1 || a <= 9) ? itos2(a) : "Greater than 9"));

   //printf("%s",itos2(a)); this doesn't crash provided a default label is set
   return 0;
}

const char* itos2(int a)
{
const char* str [] = { "one" , "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1 : return str[0];
        case 2 : return str[1];
        case 3 : return str[2];
        case 4 : return str[3];
        case 5 : return str[4];
        case 6 : return str[5];
        case 7 : return str[6];
        case 8 : return str[7];
        case 9 : return str[8];
        default: return "Greater than 9";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your condition `(a >= 1 || a <= 9)` means `a` can be either `>=0` or `<=9`. Note the `or` condition. This mean if the input is say `15`, this number is greater than `1` which makes your condition true. If the input is `-5`, it means this number is less than `9`, also making the condition true. Note the `or`.

Comment: @alvits Why answer in a comment instead of an actual answer?

Comment: thank you now i see why that default label was causing issues, my compiler didn't throw any "control reaches end of void statement warning" so i blame that too

Comment: Do not edit the solution into the question. Now it looks like you asked "I have this code: <working code goes here> and it doesn't work." I will undo all your edits, but since it's hard to tell, I might've undid something that should have stayed. In that case feel free to re-do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code, improved:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* itos2(int);

// A proper C function prototype
int main(void)
{ 
   int a;

   // Checking the return value of scanf is *required*!
   // If it doesn't return a value which is equal to the number of expected
   // assignments, then your variables are left unassigned, leading to 
   // Undefined Behavior!
   if (scanf("%i", &a) != 1) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
       return 1;
   }

   // It's usually better practice to not have to worry about a valid range
   // of inputs when calling a function. Let this function worry about the
   // input checking.
   printf("%s", itos2(a));

   return 0;
}

const char* itos2(int a)
{
    const char* str [] = {
        "zero",
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
        "four",
        "five",
        "six",
        "seven",
        "eight",
        "nine",
    };

    // Check boundary conditions. Checking just one boundary case and 
    // returning is simpler and less error-prone than your previous code.
    if (a < 0)
        return "Less than zero";
    if (a > 9)
        return "Greater than nine";

    // Why bother with a switch/case statement when you can simply
    // use the input value to index directly into an array of the strings?
    return str[a];
}
```

Assuming you're using GCC, **always** compile with *at least* this set of options:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror ...
```

Comment: i like that optimization!

Comment: @hec make sure to tell your teacher that the answer was from stackoverflow - credit where credit is due :-)

Comment: ill add it to the source code, the problem comes from hacker rank

Answer (score 4):

Condition `a >= 1 || a <= 9` is always true, meaning that your `itos2` is always called regardless of what you input as `a`. If `a` is outside of `[1, 9]` range, function `itos2` fails to return anything, producing undefined behavior (a crash in your case).

Apparently you meant `a >= 1 && a <= 9` as your condition for calling `itos2`. `&&`, not `||`.